# Robot in a grid big O explaination

Tags: java

I've done a few researches as regards this problem but I couldn't find any explain time complexity of it.

In cracking the coding interview 6th edition there is a problem:

**Robot in a Grid**: Imagine a robot sitting on the upper left corner of grid with r rows and c columns. The robot can only move in two directions, right and down, but certain cells are "off limits" such that the robot cannot step on them. Design an algorithm to find a path for the robot from the top left tothe bottom right

This is the author's solution and she explained that this problem has O(2^(r+c)) & using memoization cost O(r*c) (in which r is the number of rows and c is of columns)

"This solution is O(2^(r+c)), since each path has r+c steps and there are two choices we can make at each step"

```
ArrayList<Point> getPath(boolean[][] maze) {
2 if (maze == null || maze.length == 0) return null;
3 ArrayList<Point> path = new ArrayList<Point>()j
4 if (getPath(maze, maze.length - 1, maze[0].length - 1, path)) {
5 return path;
6 }
7 return null;
8 }
9
10 boolean getPath(boolean[][] maze, int row, int col, ArrayList<Point> path) {
11 / * If out of bounds or not available, return. */
12 if (col < 0 || row < 0 || !maze[row][col]) {
13 return false;
14 }
15
16 boolean isAtOrigin = (row == 0) && (col == 0);
17
18 /* If there's a path from the start to here, add my location. */
19 if (isAtOrigin || getPath(maze, row, col - 1, path) ||
2B getPath(maze, row - 1, col, path)) {
21 Point p = new Point(row, col);
22 path.add(p);
23 return true;
24 }
25
26 return false;
27 }
```

And when adding a hashmap to cache failed points from previous call why it cost only O(r*c) ?

```
boolean getPath(boolean[][] maze, int row, int col, ArrayList<Point> path,
12 HashSet<Point> failedPoints) {
13 /* If out of bounds or not available, return. */
14 if (col < 0 || row < 0 || !maze[row][col]) {
15 return false;
16 }
17
18 Point p = new Point(row, col);
19
20 /* If we've already visited this cell, return. */
21 if (failedPoints.contains(p)) {
22 return false;
23 }
24
25 boolean isAtOrigin = (row == 0) && (col == 0);
26
27 /* If there's a path from start to my current location, add my location. */
28 if (isAtOrigin || getpath(maze, row, col - 1, path, failedPoints) ||
29 getPath(maze, row - 1, col, path, failedPoints) {
30 path.add(p);
31 return true;
32 }
33
34 failedPoints.add(p); // Cache result
35 return false;
36 }
```

Few posts on Stackoverflow explain about how many ways you can go from start position to end which is (r+c)!/(r!c!) but I don't understand why Kayle explain the above solution is O(2^(r+c)) and using memoization costs O(r*c). Can someone explain clearly for me? I would be really appreciate if you could help.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, such problems need diagrams and GIFs to explain the algorithm in a perfect manner. However, I'll try my best to explain it by words.

1. It consumes O(2^(r+c)) because it tries every way. You need to step on r cells down and c cells right to reach your destination. Once you understand that your path is about (r+c) steps, then each cell has two choices: take it or leave it. Thus, the time complexity is O(2^(r+c)).
2. It consumes O(r*c) because memoization is used. Now, you need to try each cell only one time to find out the best use of this cell and take benefit from this result if you need it again. As your grid has r*c cells, then traversing all cells once consumes O(r*c).

I hope this helps you figure out what this problem gets.

Comment: Since each cell has 2 choices, shouldn't the first solution has O(2^(r*c)) instead of O(2^(r+c)) ?

Comment: Yes, I think so. I thought you have a problem with the second solution, so I paid more attention to it.

Comment: Could you explain more clearly about the 1st one for me ? Why should we only count (r+c) path instead of (r*c) ? Are there any particular algorithms in relation to that ?

Comment: In my opinion, it's (r*c) not (r+c) because every cell has two choices as you said. I think it will be exponential in the number of cells because this is a pure recursive problem about overlapping subproblems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that the O(2^(r+c)) time-complexity is correct. Without the hashmap, the algorithm doesn't really try every possible path. This is because of [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation) on line 19 of your first code snippet. That is, if `getpath(..., row, col - 1, ...)` returns true, the second function call `getpath(..., row - 1, col, ...)` would not be executed.

For example, if the path along the top-right edge of the grid is a valid one, the complexity will only be O(r+c).